# Tree Design for Parallel Traversal

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, load-balancing, tree-traversal

I'm working on a project that involves traversing a large unbalanced tree in a cluster of compute nodes. The tree is to be divided among the clusters. However, there would soon be load imbalance and I would invoke a Load Balancer to perform the necessary migrations. I'm having some difficulty coming up with a good design for the tree that would allow parallel traversal and simplify data partitioning.

Edit: The data distribution and migrations happen in chunks of a predetermined size(chunk size is no of nodes in the chunk). I need to figure out how to chunkify the tree so that each chunk contains data that can be traversed in a single process.

Comment: there should be no problem to traverse left and right subtree in parallel. am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Assume a tree with (big) node count T, and that the tree is static.

It is likely that entire subtrees would be useful to "keep" and process as chunks.  I'd be tempted to pick leaf trees of chunk size K (think of a big triangle), and then interior trees of size K, until the tree was tiled with such triangles.   You obviously want K big enough so that work on a triangle is efficient esp. compared to communication costs across the edges of the triangle (parent and all children), and you want it small enough so there are lots more triangles than there are compute nodes N.

An interesting problem is knowing how much communication will occur across the triangles.  I'm assuming that communication volumes through triangle tree roots is about the same cost as communication for each leaf in the triangle.

We end up with  T/K triangles.  Let's assume they are numbered according to an prefix walk of the tree, so the leftmost triangle is zero, its parent is 1, etc.

You can distribute to node n all triangles whose number is modulo N is equal to n.

You might optimize a bit.  You can send the leftmost P=(T/K)/N triangles to node 0, the next P to node 1, ...  Presumably this keeps communication across triangle boundaries to a minimum, as each node owns as big a contiguous chunk of the tree as possible.  This will also help if the amount of communication throught triangle roots is signifcantly larger than throught the leaves.  After all, you may sending large summaries up and down the tree.

You still want to process the chunks in size K because you want to distribute the work in a way that averages out evenly across all the nodes.

One standard trick used in parallel computing is outright replication of *all* the data.  That is, you may send the entire tree to every compute node if it isn't ginormous.   Then each node can decide which part of the tree it wants to process according to the above rules, but it can avoid communication when it needs to look at part of the tree that it doesn't own.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Isn't this static load balancing? I needed to simulate dynamic load imbalance to test a load balancer. But this does give me some direction.

Comment: It is static partitioning in an attempt to balance the load, yes, using modest sized trees so that each node does only modest work before switching.  You can build a load balancer on top of this: when some node runs out of work before others, it might "work steal" one of the trees.